# Types linearly-ordered by deduction?

Tags: model-theory

I'm wondering whether anyone has come across the following concept before:

Consider a first-order language $L$ and a type $p$ over a theory $T$. I say that $p$ has a *well-ordered filter-base* if there exists a transfinite sequence $(\phi_\alpha)_{\alpha < \lambda} \subseteq p$ (where $\lambda$ is some ordinal) such that $\{\phi_\alpha : \alpha < \lambda\}$ is a filter-base for $p$ (considered as a filter in the appropriate Boolean algebra) and $T \vdash (\phi_\beta \to \phi_\alpha)$ for all $\alpha < \beta < \lambda$. Such a type $p$ will correspond to a point in the space of types with a neighbourhood base linearly-ordered by $\subseteq$. I could call such a type *linear*. Of course, if the language were countable then $p$ would be countable, so I could enumerate it and take conjunctions of initial finite segments. But if $L$ were uncountable then this property becomes non-trivial.

Or more generally, what if $p$ were a p-point in the space of types; that is, for every countable subcollection $\Phi \subseteq p$, there exists a $\psi \in p$ such that $T \vdash (\psi \to \phi)$ for all $\phi \in \Phi$.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have the definition of p-point right? Shouldn't it be "for every countable $\Phi\subseteq p$, there exists $\psi\in p$ such that $\lnot\phi\land\psi$ is algebraic for all $\phi\in \Phi$"?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this notion of being algebraic (over the theory $T$?). I'm taking the topological definition of being a p-point; that is, every countable intersection of (not necessarily open) neighbourhoods is again a neighbourhood, which is easily seen to be equivalent to the above definition (I'm blurring the distinction between a formula $\phi$ and it's equivalence class under $T$-equivalence, but I hope it's fairly clear).

I'd be interested to hear about algebraicity, especially if there's this alternative definition of p-point.

Comment: I should say I've never heard of the notion of p-point applied in the space of types, I'm just trying to generalize the definition I know from the space of ultrafilters on $\omega$: $p$ is a p-point if whenever $A_i\in p$ for all $i\in \omega$, there is $B$ in $p$ such that $B\setminus A_i$ is finite for all $i$.

Comment: Now let $T$ be a complete theory and $M\models T$. A formula $\phi(\overline{x},\overline{b})$ is algebraic if $\{\overline{a}\in M\mid M\models \phi(\overline{a},\overline{b})\}$ is finite. Note that the size of this set doesn't change if we replace $M$ with an elementary extension, since the number of realizations of $\phi(\overline{x},\overline{a})$ is an elementary property of $\overline{a}$. So $\phi(\overline{x},\overline{a})$ is algebraic if and only if for any set $A$ containing $\overline{a}$, there are only finitely many types in $S(A)$ containing $\phi(\overline{x},\overline{a})$.

Comment: I don't know the topological definition of p-point that you state, but probably the issue about $B$ being contained in all $A_i$ *up to finitely many points* goes away because you don't require your neighborhoods to be clopen. Recall that in spaces of types a set is given by a formula if and only if it's clopen.

Comment: Ah, I see where your coming from. So - a free ultrafilter on $\omega$ is a p-point _precisely_  when it's a p-point the Stone space of $\mathcal{P}(\omega) / \text{Fin}$, the quotient algebra by the ideal of finite sets. Replacing this Stone space with the space of types, we arrive at the characterisation of a p-point for a complete type.